Ajax problems with WPBakery and do_shortcode
If I copy WPBakery shortcodes to a new page, it does work.
But if I render the same shortcode with do_shortcode, I can see the output, but ajax functions like "Load more" do not work.
Even if I use the addAllMappedShortcodes() method.
What is the difference to inserting the shortcodes into a page and what am I missing?
        WPBMap::addAllMappedShortcodes();

        echo do_shortcode('[vc_row][vc_column][vc_basic_grid post_type="posts" max_items="10" style="load-more" items_per_page="3"][/vc_column][/vc_row]');


If i remember correctly there's a way to output jscomposer script & style when u need them but i can't actually find the project where i needed that. Just giving you an hint here

I would suggest to move all of your functionalities to a shortcode in your functions.php and then add the shortcode to your wp-bakery page of your desire with eg. [hello_world_shortcode]
Essentialy you need to place [hello_world_shortcode] into a text block in a row in wp-bakery to view your content.
And in your functions.php
function hello_world_shortcode() {
   echo "Hello World!"
}
add_shortcode('hello_world_shortcode', 'hello_world_shortcode');

You can copy the name of your function at both of add_shortcodes parameters , and with that naming you can call them in your wp-bakery enviroment.
I think its easier to do it like this and let the wp-bakery handle the columns etc, you can alter the columns on your own anyway.
Hope my answer helped. Cheers
